# Bizarre results when launching war in EC2 using elasticsearch 0.19.8

Tags: grails, amazon-ec2, jetty, elasticsearch

I'm using Grails 2.0.4 and elasticsearch 0.19.8, with a homegrown build of the elasticsearch-grails plugin to use 0.19.8, running on a micro Ubuntu instance of EC2.

I'm building my grails project locally as a war.  When I drop this was in a jetty container locally (on my laptop), jetty starts and I'm able to navigate to the root context (as expected) and get my site.

However, when I take the same war (confirmed via md5sum) in the same version of jetty (confirmed via md5sum) on a micro EC2 instance, I get strange results.

Occasionally, jetty starts and my application is available...all is well.  But then other times, jetty won't start...and the logs are complaining about elasticsearch.

Now, I'm the first to admit that running both elasticsearch and jetty (with a grails war) on the same node is, well, not the greatest idea...but, this is a test environment, and I'm okay with swapping to disk (not a perf testing lab).

But, what's driving me batty is the inconsistency in running my application.  Currently, I cannot get it to start (which, I suppose, counters my "inconsistency" argument).  But even taking a "starting" war, with MINIMAL changes in the war (no domain object changes, just changes in controller and/or view), my app won't start - complaining about elasticsearch.

[Here's the gist](https://gist.github.com/3205132)

In the past, I've solved this by stopping elasticsearch, and blowing away `/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch` (which is basically, as I understand it, a crude way of blowing away the elasticsearch index).

But now, this doesn't appear to be working.  Neither does uninstall/reinstall elasticsearch.

Can anybody offer any advice on what to look for and/or where to look?

Comment: I don't think t1.micro instances have any swap by default, so if you're running low on memory things will probably just break

Comment: You're right...there is no swap by default.  But, I've added a 500mb file and activate swap on boot (swapon /swap)

Comment: So, the key here is this "mapper [title] has different term_vector values, mapper [description] has different term_vector values" It means that your application is trying to change mapping in the way that is incompatible with the existing mapping.

Comment: I agree...thank you.  But, as mentioned above, I'm not changing anything.  This war works great in jetty on my laptop...and barfs with this error message on my EC2 instance.

Perhaps this is the dark magic grails devs speak of?

Comment: I should also mention that I've had similar WARs running on my EC2 instance...this is not a first time deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is driving my crazy, but I found an answer.

/data contains an elasticsearch directory which, apparently, had bad data...I deleted this directory and restarted jetty and...

Viola!

I have NO idea how it got into this state, nor the actual ramifications of deleting the directory (I think elasticsearch data is persisted in the elasticsearch node...)

I suspect an incomplete shutdown of my app...

Thanks for everybody's input.